# Attaching a partition to Postgres partitioned table without Exclusive Access Lock

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

We have a table that is partitioned on a `bigint` field.

Here is an example definition :

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.demo_part
(
    n bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT demo_part_pkey PRIMARY KEY (n)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (n);
```

If we attach a default partition with :

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.demo_part_default PARTITION OF public.demo_part
```

Later partitions cannot be attached without acquiring an `AccessExclusiveLock` because the default partition must be scanned to ensure no conflicting data is in the default partition.

I tried adding `CHECK` constraints to both the partition to be added and the default partition without success.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo_part_default PARTITION OF demo_part DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE demo_part_default DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS def_check;
ALTER TABLE demo_part_default ADD CONSTRAINT def_check CHECK (n >= 1000 AND n < 500000);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo_part_1_10 (LIKE demo_part);
ALTER TABLE demo_part_1_10 DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS n_1_10;
ALTER TABLE demo_part_1_10 ADD CONSTRAINT n_1_10 CHECK (n >= 1 AND n < 10);
ALTER TABLE demo_part ATTACH PARTITION demo_part_1_10 FOR VALUES FROM (1) TO (10);
```

The later `ATTACH` always creates an `AccessExclusiveLock` even if the constraints are mutually exclusive.

Is it possible to attach a partition without `AccessExclusiveLock` when a default partition is attached ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to avoid the locked scan of the default partition.  IME default partitions are a bit toxic due to reasons like this.

Comment: This guy states that someone can relax these constraints by hand knowing what they're doing by changing the special catalog table `pg_constraint`. I am in the long process of trying this myself on an existing DB, so cannot guarantee, however here's the recipe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edQZauVU-ws&t=1684s

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this out? I'm in the same boat and am thinking I may need to rename the table and put a new table in place to write the data to while I move data from the old default partition to new partitions.